Word for a collection of awards, such as an Olympic athlete’s earned medals
Seems like there should be a word when referring to a person’s collection of earned awards.
Example:
I was awed by the display of Olympic athlete Michael Phelps’ collection of medals ______.

When it's four or more, break it up. 'Olympic athlete Michael Phelps' collection' is too much in a row. Also, display and a word for collection in the same sentence seems unnecessary. A display of medals is a collection of medals, in a sense.

@HippoSawrUs I think you’ve missed the point.

Comments are for asides; for points, see answers. It's clunky and unnecessary in that example, right? Yep.

Michael Phelps’ awards are a collection of awards. So: I was awed by the display of Olympic athlete Michael Phelps’ awards. Don’t overthink it.

I would coin awardabilia, based on the word memorabilia.

If the collection is stored in a display case, it's a trophy cabinet
It may be used figuratively to refer to the list of awards.

I've heard trophy case more frequently, and ngrams agrees. Do you think it's an exact synonym?

@BenjaminKuykendall In British English ngrams indicates that "trophy cabinet" is more frequent than "trophy case", both being synonyms, except when the trophy case is designed for a single object.

Good answer, and cabinet is definitely more common in British English, and is commonly used figuratively (this side of the pond at least).

You sometimes get references to a trophy shelf, literal or metaphorical, but I agree cabinet/case is better (and bigger).

I was awed by the display of swimmer Michael Phelps' olympic medal haul.

HAUL: noun
2a : the result of an effort to obtain, collect, or win

from Merriam-Webster
An example from Olympics.com:
Simone Biles poses with epic Olympic medal haul: “Six-year-old me would be proud”

Closer ... but would this work for cups, certificates ...?

@EdwinAshworth In another context, yes, if the vault had been full of stock certificates and ancient gold cups prior to the burglar hitting it and making off with a haul that included those items, but yeah, I see what you mean.

Good answer, but haul is more casual than I was hoping for.

Laurels
Merriam-Webster has the following definition of laurel:

3.a. a crown of laurel awarded as an honor 
3.b. a recognition of achievement (usually used in plural)

The word stems from antiquity, where an honored person would be given a crown of laurels.  (If you see a picture of a Roman emperor with some leaves on their head, that's what those are.)  In more recent times the word has been used figuratively to stand for the honours and awards that a person has earned.
This said, my sense of the word is that it is more typically used in the context of things like government, literature, sciences, and so forth;  using "laurels" here might be confusing to the reader.  If you called them "athletic laurels" it might be clearer.


I was awed by the tally of accolades earned by Michael Phelps.

The rather formal term, accolade, can also refer to words of praise and positive reviews but that interpretation is tempered by the noun tally.
accolade
(via Oxford Languages)
an award or privilege granted as a special honour or as an acknowledgement of merit.
"the hotel has won numerous accolades"
(via Merriam-Webster)
1 a
: a mark of acknowledgment : award
received the highest accolade of his profession
(via Cambridge Dictionary)
receive an accolade
He's been granted the ultimate accolade - his face on a postage stamp.
(via Collins Dictionary)
British English
1. strong praise or approval; acclaim
2. an award or honour
American English
1. any award, honor, or laudatory notice
The play received accolades from the press
2. a light touch on the shoulder with the flat side of the sword or formerly by an embrace, done in the ceremony of conferring knighthood.

I've actually upvoted for (his medal) tally, rather  than accolades.

@FumbleFingers The only problem with medals is, it doesn't include trophies, statuettes, ribbons, prizes etc.

There seems to be redundancy in the example sentence by saying both display and collection.
A trophy isn't a collection, but

I was awed by the display of Olympic athlete Michael Phelps’ trophies.

might work for you.

A trophy isn't a collection, and only a true collective noun would be suitable on a site aimed at linguists.

@EdwinAshworth your put-down perhaps misses my point that the 'display' is the collection, with 'trophies' used for the various awards. The post already said "a trophy isn't a collection".

'Trophy' doesn't work as it isn't a collective noun, but 'display' and 'collection' are far too broad to be answers for 'a [single] word for a collection of awards'.

I think it's fair to say the answer is 'medals'. "I was awed by the display of Olympic athlete Michael Phelps’ medals."

'Medals' aren't a collection of various trophies, and only a true collective noun would be suitable on a site aimed at linguists.

Clutch
Merriam-Webster has the following definition of clutch:

clutch
noun (2)

a nest of eggs or a brood of chicks
group, bunch


talking with a clutch of her friends
a clutch of photographs
a clutch of reporters


An example from Loughborough University:
Loughborough athletes return to UK with clutch of medals
Or from the BBC:
The 100m silver from the 1973 All African Games in Nigeria stands out amid Amankwaah's clutch of medals

Palmarès
I have heard it several times used to refer (albeit not its primary meaning, which is from Latin list of winners) to the collection of medals and prizes of an athlete. Not, however, as a physical object, so it might be a poor fit for a medal cabinet.
From Wiktionary (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palmar%C3%A8s), emphasis mine:

palmarès m (uncountable)

prize list; list of winners
record of achievements


Possibly also tally.

the meaning is spot on but its use is pretty much exclusive to cycling, I believe

@AakashM I agree. I have never heard it used outside of cycling. But it is very common in that field. If you watch any big bicycle race on TV (like a Tour de France stage, the Olympic road-race or time-trail) the commentators are sure to use the term palmarès several times per hour.

The word "panoply" is defined by dictionary.com as "a wide-ranging and impressive array or display".  Originally, it referred to a suit of armor, which perhaps applies especially well to a large, wearable collection of metal disks like Olympic medals.
See https://www.dictionary.com/browse/panoply.
